# Firebase Cloud function event - sometime not getting data on update event

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have written firebase cloud function to trigger on update record. sometimes I am not getting the same record which is updating. I am adding my code below.Please check attached image also.

```
exports.onNotificationUpdate = functions.database.ref('/Notification/{userId}/{notificationId}/userResponse').onUpdate(event => {
    return admin.database().ref(`/Notification/${event.params.userId}/${event.params.notificationId}`).once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
        var notification = snapshot.val();

        if (!notification) {
            console.error("Notification not found on notification update");
            return;
        };
```

I can also get Notification object from the parent but I want to know issue best approach and the problem with this code.

[this is error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9yN8.png)

[this is database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qm7sz.png)

This is my 1st post here please let me know if need more information.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to call `once` within the Function since it is already returning the data at the location you are listening to, just listen to the parent node.

So you should do like:

```
exports.onNotificationUpdate = functions.database.ref('/Notification/{userId}/{notificationId}').onUpdate(event => {
        const notification = event.data.val(); 

        if (notification === null) {
            console.error("Notification not found on notification update");
            return null;
            //actually this would only be called in case of deletion of the Notification
        } else {
            //do something with the notification data: send Android notification, send mail, write in another node of the database, etc.
           //BUT return a Promise
           //notification const declared above is a JavaScript object containing what is under this node (i.e. a similar structure than your database structure as shown in the image within your post.)
        }
});
```

I would suggest that you have a look at these three videos from the Firebase team:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA&t=517s

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=652XeeKNHSk&t=27s

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d9GrysWH1Lc

Also, note that Cloud Functions have been updated and the first line of your code shall be written differently if you are using  a CF version above 1.0.0. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff

Comment: Thank you so much, please see I need this /Notification/{userId}/{notificationId}/ object in notification variable  not  /Notification/{userId}/{notificationId}/userResponse. I added update event on /Notification/{userId}/{notificationId}/userResponse. I got your answer, should I get notification by parent call?

Comment: No you should listen at the level of the parent node, i.e. /`Notification/{userId}/{notificationId}`. I have updated my answer. Also, I permit myself to insist: have a look at those 3 videos (at least the 2 first ones), they are a must for anyone who starts working with Cloud Functions. It will not be a waste of time, but a genuine investment.

Comment: did you have the time to look at this solution? You may consider accepting it, thanks.